# Auto rotate animation on Three.js

Tags: three.js

I'm using Three.js in order to render a 3D element.
I work with `mousemove` in order to rotate the scene with the movement of the mouse.

I'm looking to add an animation that slightly rotates the scene automatically.

It essentially would emulate the rotation done via mouse movement but automatically so the object doesn't appear static when loading.

Does someone know a trivial way to achieve that?
Thanks in advance,

```
$(function() {

var logoSrc = './assets/vector_gltf/scene.gltf';
var renderer,
    scene,
    camera,
    holder = document.getElementById('holder');
    canvas = document.getElementById('canvasLogo');

renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
  canvas: canvas,
  antialias: true,
  alpha: true,
});

renderer.setSize($(holder).width(), $(holder).height());
holder.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

renderer.setClearColor( 0x000000, 0 );
renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
// renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
//on resize
window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
  // Update camera
  camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
  // Update renderer
  // renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  renderer.setSize($(holder).width(), $(holder).height());
  holder.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
  renderer.setPixelRatio(Math.min(window.devicePixelRatio, 2));
});

camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(55, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );

scene = new THREE.Scene();

var light = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x0000ff, 1);
scene.add(light);
var light2 = new THREE.PointLight(0xff0000, 1);
scene.add(light2);

var loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();
loader.load(logoSrc, handle_load);
var s;var mesh;
function handle_load(gltf) {
  s = gltf.scene;
  mesh = s.children[0].children[0].children[0];
  // s.children[0].material = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({
  //   normalMap : logoSrc + 'textures/StingrayPBS1SG_normal.png',
  //   emissiveMap : logoSrc + 'textures/StingrayPBS1SG_emissive.png',
  //   metalnessMap : logoSrc + 'textures/StingrayPBS1SG_metallicRoughness.png',
  //   map : logoSrc + 'textures/StingrayPBS1SG_baseColor.png'
  // });
  scene.add(s);
  s.position.y = -0.2;
  s.position.z = -2;//15
}

$(".intro").on("mousemove", function(e){
  mesh.rotation.set(-0.003 * (e.pageY - window.innerHeight / 20),0, -0.02 * (e.pageX - (window.innerWidth / 2) - 3.14));
  //.set(0.0018 * (e.pageY - 291.45) - 1.45,0, 0.02 * (e.pageX - (window.innerWidth / 2) - 3.14))
});

//anim
const clock = new THREE.Clock();
const loop = () =>
{
  const elapsedTime = clock.getElapsedTime();//delta time
  // Render
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
  // Call tick again on the next frame
  window.requestAnimationFrame(loop);
}
loop();

});
```

Answer (score 2):

This is what you want: http://threejs.org/examples/misc_controls_orbit.html

Include the [orbit controls](https://threejs.org/docs/?q=orbit#examples/en/controls/OrbitControls) (after you have downloaded them):

```js
<script src="js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
```

Setup the variable:

```js
var controls;
```

Attach the controls to the camera and add a listener:

```js
controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera );
controls.addEventListener( 'change', render );
```

and in your animate function update the controls:

```js
controls.update();
controls.autoRotate();
```

That last line ([autoRotate](https://threejs.org/docs/?q=orbit#examples/en/controls/OrbitControls.autoRotate)) is really what you want for the rotation, but everything else is setting up your controls.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function called `animate()` that is making your 3D element move automatically and combining it to a `render()` method.

```js
function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame( animate );
  group.rotation += 0.005;
  render();
}

function render() {
  renderer.render( scene, camera );
}
```

Comment: thanks so much for this! I'm a total newbie in Three.js so I was wondering where these auto rotate settings must be placed?

Comment: They can be placed in the file you want them to have an impact. You can do it by creating a new `const` as such  : `const controls = new OrbitControls( camera, render.domElement )`

Comment: This is incorrect. Orbit control will rotate if the user wants too, but not automatically like asked.

Comment: I just updated my answer @Anta

Comment: This still doesn't work... you need to rotate the camera, not an arbitrary group.

Comment: Yes exactly that is why I wrote `grouping order to let somebody choose the `group` they want

Comment: See my answer for clarity